# How to stress test a correlation matrix

Tags: mean-variance, correlation-matrix, stress-testing

As part of a mean variance portfolio task, I am calculating portfolio risk and optimal allocations between assets given required level of return. Input: expected returns, volatility and correlation matrix. So far so good.

As a second part, I am supposed to stress input correlation matrix by some multiplier (say 1.3) and see how to it impacts the allocations and portfolio risk.

The question I have is: can I just multiply all fields in the correlation matrix by the given multiplier? It seems wrong to me as I would end up with "self correlation" > 1 on the diagonal, which makes no sense? Should I just keep diagonal as 1s and only multiply the rest? What if the multiplier is such that correlation between i and j will be >1 anyway? Any ideas appreciated, thank you.

NOTE: No risk free asset in this scenario, but it shouldn't matter.

Comment: As an ad-hoc fix you could set $\rho_{ij}:=\max[-1,\min[1,1.3 \rho_{ij}]]$. That is multiply by 1.3 but then limit it to be between -1 and 1.

Comment: thats what I ended up doing, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the correlation matrix will most probably become non-positive-semi-definite with such an *ad hoc* manipulation, you may try one of the following:

1. **Still run that algorithm** and *check* that the resulting matrix is still positive (semi) definite.
2. **Bootstrapp** the correlation matrix, or the volatilities, or both, from your input data.
3. Manipulate the **eigenvalues of your correlation matrix**, e.g. by shifting more weight to the first eigenvalues (increasing correlations, overall) and then normalise the hypothetical correlation matrix obtained by multiplying your original eigenvectors with your shifted eigenvectors.

IMHO, option 2 has the most merit as it incorporates the empirical variability of the correlation matrix estimation into your portfolio selection process.